# Global Layout for Angular2 Project

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular2-template, primeng

I get a project which I have to develop in `angular2` with `typescript`. I have implemented heros example with the help of angular2 website. But now I want to develop a **global layout** for my project. The past two days, I tried to implement many examples but they are very big. So I am facing challenges to merge my existing code into those projects.

I have tried two examples :

1. http://rawgit.com/start-angular/ani-angular-2/master/dist/prod/index.html#/dashboard
2. http://akveo.com/ng2-admin/#/pages/dashboard

Can somebody provide me a hint on how to do that?

Comment: Friends please help me out here it you have any small project with good css design layout . Please share with me

Answer (score 0):

Sure,

Take some puppy love from here https://github.com/kara/puppy-love

https://puppy-love.firebaseapp.com/

Comment: Thanks for your help. But when my browser trying to load it gives an error in console that @angular2-material package is not found. Please suggest me if I am doing something wrong.